# For what vectors will $I-uv^*$ be singular?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u,v$ be $1\times m$ vectors. For what vectors $u$ and $v$ will $A:=I-uv^*$ be singular? And if it is singular, what is its nullity?

My approach is that the rank of $uv^*$ is $1$, so $m-1$ eigenvalues are zero and one of the eigenvalues of $uv^*$ must be $1$. This is because $(I-uv^*)x=(1-\lambda')x$, $x\ne 0$. Now, we can represent the characteristic polynomial of $uv^*$ as $\lambda'^{(m-1)}(\lambda'-u_{ij} \overline{v}_{ji})$ for some $i,j$. Does this imply that $u,v$ must satisfy the condition that $u$ and $v$ must have one entry $u_{ij}$ and $v_{ij}$ such that $u_{ij}v_{ji}=1$, that is $u_{ij}$ and $v_{ji}$ are roots of unity, and are equal?

Comment: There is a general result that $\det(I+AB) = \det (I+BA)$. (This follows from the fact that $AB,BA$ have the same non zero eigenvalues.) Another approach is to try and compute the inverse explicitly, this will reveal the relevant 'determinant' criterion (cf. Sherman Morrison formula.

Answer (score 1):

$$\DeclareMathOperator{vspan}{span}$$I don't think your expression for the characteristic polynomial is correct (since $u, v$ are vectors, they should only have on index).  I suspect that if you fix the expression, you would get the correct result (which includes more vectors than what you have currently).

However, there is an easier way to simplify the problem.  As you noticed, the problem is equivalent to finding when $uv^*$ has an eigenvalue of $1$.  Notice that
$$(uv^*)w = (v^*w)u$$

so the eigenvector of $uv^*$ must be $u$.  On the other hand, 
$$(uv^*)u = (v^*u)u$$
so the eigenvalue of $u$ is $v^*u$.  Thus, the condition is that $v^*u = 1$.

---

copper.hat in the comments to the question mentions the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).  This formula gives the expression for $(A + uv^*)^{-1}$ in terms of $A^{-1}$, $u$, and $v$.  In particular, it states that
$$(A + uv^*)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1}u v^* A^{-1}}{1 + v^* A^{-1} u}.$$
Taking $A = I$, we see that we can compute $(I + uv^*)^{-1}$ whenever $1 + v^*u \neq 0$, confirming our prior calculation.

Comment: Can you please clarify how we can derive that $(uv^*)w=(v^*w)u$? Also, how does this imply that $u$ is the eigenvector of $uv^*$?

Comment: Well, $(uv^*)w = u(v^*w)$ by associativity.  But, $v^*w$ is just a scalar, so we can move it to the front.  It we define $A = uv^*$, $\lambda = v^*w$,  then we've just found that
$$Au = \lambda u$$
so $u$ must be an eigenvector of $A = uv^*$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(\lambda,w)$ be an eigenpair of $A$,then
$$Aw = (I - uv^*)w = \lambda w$$i.e.
$$w - (v^*w)u = \lambda w$$
Let $\lambda = 0$, then
$$w = (v^*w)u \tag{1}$$
This means that an eigenvector in the null space should be along $u$, hence $w = \alpha u$ and therefore $(1)$ becomes
$$(v^*\alpha u)u = \alpha u $$
which gives
$$(v^*u)u = u $$

> which means that $v^*u = 1$. This is the only condition you need so that $I - uv^*$ is singular. Also, and as you argue, this will mean that under the condition that $v^*u = 1$, the only eigenvector in the null-space is $u$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why an eigenvector is in the nullspace? Also, how do you formally determine that $(v^*u)u=u$ implies $v^* u =1$?